# How to realtime monitor a specific logcat on android?

Tags: android, android-camera

My app is record camera preview every 5 minute.

but sometimes occur
`W/EGL-DRI2: Could not dequeue buffer from native window
E/BufferQueueProducer: [GraphicBufferSource] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned`.

so I want if when occur this log, Immediately stop record camera preview..

this problem is possible? if possible, Is there a way to realtime monitor logs?

thanks.